# How to print specific numbers with loop in C?

Tags: c

I have a program where I have to print months and specific numbers of "~". I have one function called: graphLine

```
    void graphLine(int month,const struct MonthlyStatistic* monthly){

    int totalStars;
    int i;
    int j;

    total = (monthly->totalPrecipitation * 10.0) / 10.0;

    for (j=0;j<total;j++) {
          printf("%d  | ~ \n", month);
    }


}
```

and I have main function which calls this functions using a loop:

```
for (i=0;i<12;i++){
    graphLine(i+1,&monthly[i]);
}
```

the problem is that I want to print specific number of ~ depending on result of variable total in graphLine, but I can't use a loop in graphLine becaue if I do it would overlap with for loop in main.
So how can I use a loop in graphLine function, so that I print a result something like this:

```
1 | ~~~~
2 | ~~~
3 | ~~~~~~~~~
.......
```

Thanks

Comment: "I can't use a loop in graphLine becaue if I do it would overlap with for loop in main." **Why on the earth** do you think so?

Comment: Where do you define `total`? Avoiding using global variables unless you need to use ones is a good practice.

Comment: Why can't you print `month` in `main()` and the tildes(`~`) inside the `graphLine` function?
That should help!

Comment: Note that `total = (monthly->totalPrecipitation * 10.0) / 10.0;` is exactly the same as `total = monthly->totalPrecipitation;`

Answer (score 2):

Use this trick:

```
void print_month_stats(int month, int count) {
    const char *maxbar = "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~";

    printf("%d  | %.*s\n", month, count, maxbar);
}
```

`printf` will print `count` tildes, upto the length of `maxbar`.
This trick is most convenient if you want to print some pattern, such as `----+----+--` or `\/\/\/\/\/\/\` or even `1234567890123456789012345`.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am bit confused as to how your solution works. What I really wanted to do is to print tildes up to the variable total in graphLine function. This work, but it print same numbers of ~ in every line.

Comment: What is the value of `count`?  It should print count tildes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

```
total = (monthly->totalPrecipitation * 10.0) / 10.0;

printf( "%d | ", month );
for (j=0;j<total;j++) 
{
  putchar( '~' );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Comment: Quick and simple solution... I still wonder why the OP needs the `* 10.0 / 10.0` part?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you print month in `main` and the tildes(`~`) inside the `graphLine` function?

In `main`:

```
for (i=0;i<12;i++){
   printf("%d | ",i+1); 
   graphLine(i+1,&monthly[i]);
}
```

And the `graphLine` function

```
void graphLine(int month,const struct MonthlyStatistic* monthly){

int totalStars;
int i;
int j;

total = (monthly->totalPrecipitation * 10.0) / 10.0;

for (j=0;j<total;j++) {
      printf("~");
}
printf("\n");
```

}